# What is a SELECT statement to find these records?

Tags: sql

I need help with SELECT query to find/return BETWEEN dates I need from DB where a field is TRANSACTIONDATE and displays these dates in non-standard form date.

For example, I need to find all records from 12/10/2020 to 01/05/2021.

```
'12192020 000'
'12202020 000'
'12202021 000'
'12202022 000'
...
'01052021 000'
'01062021 000'
```

Any help will be appreciated.
.

Comment: what database you're using ? MS SQL/MySql ??

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Also, tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: @jarlh I would argue that we should talk about _tuples_ and _attributes_ :)

Comment: @jarlh Some people say exactly the opposite. This is not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have no information about the DBMS (e.g. Postgres, MySQL, MS SQL, ...) I can only propose a general idea of how to tackle this.

You will have to transform these (string?) values into real dates to use operators like BETWEEN. Usually this will be done by a built in function similar to `to_date(TRANSACTIONDATE, 'mmddyyyy')` where the second parameter is a format string that tells the database for each character in the string its meaning. From the given values I assume that the first two characters represent the month, the next two the day and the last four the year.

Your query could look something like this
`SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE to_date(TRANSACTIONDATE, 'mmddyyyy') BETWEEN from_value AND to_value;`
The details vary depending on the used DBMS.

Comment: Correct outline, two additions: possibly first the unnecessary chunk from the space needs to be removed before casting. Also possilby if the second parameter is not supported by the casting, then collation needs to be supplied.